# Jenkins only compiles last change

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit

I'm having some issues with jenkins and gerrit.
We have some jobs that verifies changes on the master branch.

this is the configuration i have:

## **Git**

URL of repository: ssh://jenkins_user@localhost:29418/project
- Name of repository: Gerrit
- Refspec: +refs/changes/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
- Branch Specifier: **

## **Execution Triggers**

- Check Repository
- Scheduler: * * * * * (every minute)

## **Gerrit Integration**

- Gerrit Host: localhost
- Gerrit Username: jenkins_user
- Private Key File Path : path_to_key/key_rsa

The problem is when we push multiple changes to the master branch

```
git push origin work:refs/for/master
```

jenkins does one build for each change, but it always build the last change.

This happens with 2 out of 3 jobs (each one belongs to different projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build changes you pushed to Gerrit for review (i.e. these changes are not submitted yet), then you have to use the [Gerrit Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) and not the other triggers.
The wiki page explains it good, how you have to configure the Gerrit trigger event. However, if you have problems, write a comment.